# Serve app in smartphone throught localhost

Tags: angular, angular-cli, smartphone

Hi im making an app with angular cli, and im serving it to the local host 4200... is there a way to open the app also in my smartphone? i have an iphone 6. but also with andorid.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it if your phone is in the same wifi then the machine running ng serve.
You would have to run `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` and then type into your phone

`http://<ip-of-your-ng-serve-machine>:4200`